# How to highlight important points of your text?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

A while back quotation by > was done with a orange box.

The new quotation box is visually very bland. One might like that, one may not. That's fine.

I remember that highlighting questions or other stuff like that was never really encouraged. I never understood this, as I found it made a post much more readable.

I miss an easy way to highlight important parts of a question, or answer. Is there a work around, or which options could you use?

There were similar questions in the past, but as it seems they never really got answered.

Comment: > plus ** text **, maybe.

Comment: Bold-face is obnoxious, especially when over-used, @VeronicaR.M.  And rarely is it *not* overused.

Comment: You could try using color (although that can also be obnoxious, if not used sparingly).

Comment: I would like to avoid colour, because - as you said - it is pretty obnoxious. I felt like the orange boxes were fairly pleasent to the eye. Using colorued text would break it, I think.

Comment: Cornman  I agree with your assessment, that the former text box was far superior to the grey on white text box used currently available.  This would make a great question on [meta.se], because this was an SE developer's decision to change.  Don't fix what wasn't broken!

Answer (score -1):

### How about something like this?

$$ \bbox[yellow,5px,border:3px solid black]
{
\substack{\\ \large\text{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut} \\ \large\text{labore et dolore 
magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco} \\
\large\text{laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure 
dolor in reprehenderit in} \\ \large\text{voluptate velit esse cillum dolore 
eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat } 
\\ \large\text{non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim 
id est laborum.}\\\\\\\\\\ \large\mathbf{\text{You can also add some math:}}
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ \displaystyle\int x^2 \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{x^3}{3} + C\\\\\\}
}
$$

```
$$ \bbox[yellow,5px,border:3px solid black]
{
\substack{\\ \large\text{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut} \\ \large\text{labore et dolore 
magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco} \\
\large\text{laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure 
dolor in reprehenderit in} \\ \large\text{voluptate velit esse cillum dolore 
eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat } 
\\ \large\text{non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim 
id est laborum.}\\\\\\\\\\ \large\mathbf{\text{You can also add some math:}}
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ \displaystyle\int x^2 \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{x^3}{3} + C\\\\\\}
}
$$
```

**You may also use other colours, such as orange in place of yellow:**

$$ \bbox[orange,5px,border:3px solid black]
{
\substack{\\ \large\text{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut} \\ \large\text{labore et dolore 
magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco} \\
\large\text{laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure 
dolor in reprehenderit in} \\ \large\text{voluptate velit esse cillum dolore 
eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat } 
\\ \large\text{non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim 
id est laborum.}\\\\\\\\\\ \large\mathbf{\text{You can also add some math:}}
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ \displaystyle\int x^2 \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{x^3}{3} + C\\\\\\}
}
$$

**Or even a custom color with its hex color code:**

$$ \bbox[#ADD8E6,5px,border:3px solid black]
{
\substack{\\ \large\text{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut} \\ \large\text{labore et dolore 
magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco} \\
\large\text{laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure 
dolor in reprehenderit in} \\ \large\text{voluptate velit esse cillum dolore 
eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat } 
\\ \large\text{non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim 
id est laborum.}\\\\\\\\\\ \large\mathbf{\text{You can also add some math:}}
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\ \displaystyle\int x^2 \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{x^3}{3} + C\\\\\\}
}
$$

*The border colour and width can also be customised.*

Comment: I find it unpleasant to the eye, but thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @Cornman You can also use other colours such as orange which is more pleasant to the eye.

Comment: I actually thought this was quite good. Sadly idk how to use this latex code... should learn..

Comment: I don't think mathjax should be used for text formatting.

Comment: @MaoWao Well, it'd be great if SE can introduce some accessible highlighting features but in the mean time, this is a good work around.